# How to send push notification node.js everlive

Tags: node.js, push-notification, push, everlive

I want to push notification with node.js but the module in node.js don't have the send method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the notification object like this documentation : http://docs.telerik.com/platform/backend-services/development/javascript-sdk/push-notifications/sending-push-from-client

```
el.data('Push/Notifications').create(notification, function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }, function(e) {
                        console.log(e);
                    });
```